# ruby reflection - accessing values in an each block

Tags: ruby, reflection

Title is weak as I'm not exactly sure how to describe this one.

In Ruby an array can be iterated over, eg (here's a trivial example, but **any** parameter could be passed

```
[Integer.class, String.class, Module.class].each do |_|
  puts _
end
```

This will return `Class`\n`Class`\n`Class`

Is it possible to get the actual value of each array object, ideally from within the each block?

eg `Integer.class, String.class, Module.class`

Another example, this time the originals that are expected are "1+1" and "2+2",  eg as strings, **not the result**

```
[1+1,2+2].each do |n|
  puts n
end
```

can you get the contents of the "original element" , eg [1+1],[2+2]?

- If the command is first stored as a string, the "command" and the "result" can be accessed using something like

```
["1+1","2+2"].each do |n|
  puts "calculating #{n}"
  puts eval n
end
```

I'm wondering if something similar is possible (output n), *without* storing the commands as strings. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: The expressions inside the array literal are evaluated before `each` is called. Within the array only the results exist. There’s no way to retrieve the expressions other than inspecting the source code.

Comment: Ruby does provide the `Ripper` class but you would need access to read the source code, parse the lines appropriately to isolate the loops,....., and even still it would be extremely fragile; however with your trivial example `Ripper.tokenize('[Integer.class, String.class, Module.class].each { puts _1 }').take_while {|e| e != 'each'}[1..-3].join.split(",") #=> ["Integer.class", " String.class", " Module.class"]`

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? What are you hoping to get at the end of this? It would be helpful to know what your expected result is.

```rb
 [Integer, String, Module].each do |x|
   x
 end
=> [Integer, String, Module]
```

You're asking the Integer for its class, which is an instance of `Class` if you wanted the class name then you should ask the instance of class for it's name `Integer.class.name`.

Comment: Thanks for reply Danny, updated to try to explain, it's whatever the "element" is (maybe a method parameter or argument). This is re Ruby reflection, proof-of-concept. Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

As far i know it is not possible to do as you describe. When you define an array with expressions like [1+1, 2+2], Ruby calculates the values of those expressions and stores the results in the array. In this case, 1+1 is 2, and 2+2 is 4, so the array becomes [2, 4].

Converting the array to string works as you described if the array is dynamically added: `%w[1+1 2+2]`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

In Ruby, almost everything is an expression, and expressions are generally evaluated left to right. That means that passing in expressions like `1+1` happen before that expression is passed to your block. So, you either need to pass in each element of your expression separately, or parse a literal into something else inside your block.

As a simpler alternative, I also show an example of how you can use Kernel#eval safely, provided you aren't iterating over untrusted or tainted data. This is a bit more elegant, but only safe to use when you can guarantee the safety of the objects you're evaluating.

### Iterating Over Sub-Arrays

As a trivial example, you could pass in sub-arrays. Assuming you will always be doing addition:

```rb
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].map { p _1, _2; _1 + _2 }
1
2
3
4
=> [3, 7]
```

Or, if you want each sub-array, you could take this approach using #tap or extending your #map block to print the elements of your sub-arrays:

```rb
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].tap { p _1, _2 }.map { _1 + _2 }
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
=> [3, 7]
```

### Parsing String Objects into Integers and Math Operations

If you're storing each item as a String object, then you need to split it into Integer and operator elements first. For example:

```rb
["1+2", "2*2"].map do |str|
  str.match(/(\d+)([+-\/*])(\d+)/) do
    pp $&.to_s
    $1.to_i.send($2.to_sym, $3.to_i)
  end
end
```

This will print and return:

```rb
"1+2"
"2*2"
=> [3, 4]
```

---

##### Important Notes on Permissive Casting

*Calling [String#to_i](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en//master/String.html#method-i-to_i) is fairly permissive, so a `nil` or empty String will evaluate as `0`. This may not be what you want, in which case you should refactor using something like [Kernel#Integer](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en//master/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) on the value instead. You can also expand your block to do other validations, but the point is that there are edge cases with String#to_i and [String#to_sym](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en//master/String.html#method-i-to_sym) that you should be aware of.*

---

### Using [Kernel#eval](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en//master/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) Safely

While unsafe on tainted data, if you just want the simplest thing that could possibly work and aren't using user input or outside data, using #eval would work, too. For example:

```rb
h = {}
["1+2", "2*2"].map { h[_1] = eval(_1) }
# => [3, 4]

h
#=> {"1+2"=>3, "2*2"=>4}
```

People will tell you [Kernel#eval](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en//master/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) is unsafe, and it is when you're dealing with arbitrary data, but in this case you *know* what's being passed in. Specifically, you're passing in a known set of simple math operations as String objects that *you* have written, and so this is a perfectly valid use of the #eval method.

If you're dealing with untrusted data or user input, use one of the other alternatives instead, or make sure you perform some sort of validation and sanitization first. This avoids executing arbitrary code when you call #eval on the String.